# Can I put <form> in table as a modal

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about form in table if I put the form inside the table as a modal there is a red bar and dont equal to the end tag form, I would like to know if im following rules or bad coding in html?

```
  <table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
   <?php 
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
   $id=$_GET["id"];
 $sqls = "SELECT resident_id, complaints_id, nature_of_complaints, status 
 FROM table_complaints WHERE resident_id=?";

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt );
    if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt ) > 0) {

  while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt )) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-transform: capitalize"><?php echo 
                   substr($nature_of_complaints,0,8);?>..</td>
    <td style="text-transform: capitalize"><?php 
                    echo $status?></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('id016<?php echo 
           $complaints_id?>').style.display='block'" >Add</a></td>
 </tr>

 <div id="id016<?php echo $complaints_id?>" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <header> 
             <p>Involvement</p>
         </header>
 <form action="involvement.php" method="POST">
    <input name="resid" value="<?php echo $resident_id?>" type="hidden">
    <input name="compid" value="<?php echo $complaints_id?>" type="hidden">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
  </form>
   </div>
     <footer>
     <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id016<?php echo 
        $complaints_id?>').style.display='none'">Close</button>
    </footer>
   <?php 
    }
} else {   ?>
<tbody><tr><td><?php echo "No Complaints";?></td></tr></tbody>
   <?php
}

  </table>
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421631/modal-for-clickable-table-rows-in-bootstrap  Bootstrap is better for this kind of solutions.

Comment: it is okay to put form in table?

Comment: Yes you can and depends upon how standard code you are writing.